# Failed homebrew installation on MacBook Pro m1

Tags: bash, git, terminal, homebrew, sudo

I get the below error when trying to install homebrew on my MacBook.The installer fails at the same point every time.

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-3:~ jordan$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/
opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/etc
/opt/homebrew/include
/opt/homebrew/lib
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/opt/homebrew/share
/opt/homebrew/var
/opt/homebrew/opt
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
/opt/homebrew/var/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked
/opt/homebrew/Cellar
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom
/opt/homebrew/Frameworks

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod ug=rwx /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown jordan /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R jordan:admin /opt/homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Users/jordan/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Users/jordan/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R jordan /Users/jordan/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 239991, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3091/3091), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1528/1528), done.
remote: Total 239991 (delta 1554), reused 2912 (delta 1483), pack-reused 236900
Receiving objects: 100% (239991/239991), 69.99 MiB | 11.47 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (175237/175237), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
 * [new branch]          master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]             0.1        -> 0.1
 * [new tag]             0.2        -> 0.2
 * [new tag]             0.3        -> 0.3
 * [new tag]             0.4        -> 0.4
 * [new tag]             0.5        -> 0.5
 * [new tag]             0.6        -> 0.6
 * [new tag]             0.7        -> 0.7
 * [new tag]             0.7.1      -> 0.7.1
 * [new tag]             0.8        -> 0.8
 * [new tag]             0.8.1      -> 0.8.1
 * [new tag]             0.9        -> 0.9
 * [new tag]             0.9.1      -> 0.9.1
 * [new tag]             0.9.2      -> 0.9.2
 * [new tag]             0.9.3      -> 0.9.3
 * [new tag]             0.9.4      -> 0.9.4
 * [new tag]             0.9.5      -> 0.9.5
 * [new tag]             0.9.8      -> 0.9.8
 * [new tag]             0.9.9      -> 0.9.9
 * [new tag]             1.0.0      -> 1.0.0
 * [new tag]             1.0.1      -> 1.0.1
 * [new tag]             1.0.2      -> 1.0.2
 * [new tag]             1.0.3      -> 1.0.3
 * [new tag]             1.0.4      -> 1.0.4
 * [new tag]             1.0.5      -> 1.0.5
 * [new tag]             1.0.6      -> 1.0.6
 * [new tag]             1.0.7      -> 1.0.7
 * [new tag]             1.0.8      -> 1.0.8
 * [new tag]             1.0.9      -> 1.0.9
 * [new tag]             1.1.0      -> 1.1.0
 * [new tag]             1.1.1      -> 1.1.1
 * [new tag]             1.1.10     -> 1.1.10
 * [new tag]             1.1.11     -> 1.1.11
 * [new tag]             1.1.12     -> 1.1.12
 * [new tag]             1.1.13     -> 1.1.13
 * [new tag]             1.1.2      -> 1.1.2
 * [new tag]             1.1.3      -> 1.1.3
 * [new tag]             1.1.4      -> 1.1.4
 * [new tag]             1.1.5      -> 1.1.5
 * [new tag]             1.1.6      -> 1.1.6
 * [new tag]             1.1.7      -> 1.1.7
 * [new tag]             1.1.8      -> 1.1.8
 * [new tag]             1.1.9      -> 1.1.9
 * [new tag]             1.2.0      -> 1.2.0
 * [new tag]             1.2.1      -> 1.2.1
 * [new tag]             1.2.2      -> 1.2.2
 * [new tag]             1.2.3      -> 1.2.3
 * [new tag]             1.2.4      -> 1.2.4
 * [new tag]             1.2.5      -> 1.2.5
 * [new tag]             1.2.6      -> 1.2.6
 * [new tag]             1.3.0      -> 1.3.0
 * [new tag]             1.3.1      -> 1.3.1
 * [new tag]             1.3.2      -> 1.3.2
 * [new tag]             1.3.3      -> 1.3.3
 * [new tag]             1.3.4      -> 1.3.4
 * [new tag]             1.3.5      -> 1.3.5
 * [new tag]             1.3.6      -> 1.3.6
 * [new tag]             1.3.7      -> 1.3.7
 * [new tag]             1.3.8      -> 1.3.8
 * [new tag]             1.3.9      -> 1.3.9
 * [new tag]             1.4.0      -> 1.4.0
 * [new tag]             1.4.1      -> 1.4.1
 * [new tag]             1.4.2      -> 1.4.2
 * [new tag]             1.4.3      -> 1.4.3
 * [new tag]             1.5.0      -> 1.5.0
 * [new tag]             1.5.1      -> 1.5.1
 * [new tag]             1.5.10     -> 1.5.10
 * [new tag]             1.5.11     -> 1.5.11
 * [new tag]             1.5.12     -> 1.5.12
 * [new tag]             1.5.13     -> 1.5.13
 * [new tag]             1.5.14     -> 1.5.14
 * [new tag]             1.5.2      -> 1.5.2
 * [new tag]             1.5.3      -> 1.5.3
 * [new tag]             1.5.4      -> 1.5.4
 * [new tag]             1.5.5      -> 1.5.5
 * [new tag]             1.5.6      -> 1.5.6
 * [new tag]             1.5.7      -> 1.5.7
 * [new tag]             1.5.8      -> 1.5.8
 * [new tag]             1.5.9      -> 1.5.9
 * [new tag]             1.6.0      -> 1.6.0
 * [new tag]             1.6.1      -> 1.6.1
 * [new tag]             1.6.10     -> 1.6.10
 * [new tag]             1.6.11     -> 1.6.11
 * [new tag]             1.6.12     -> 1.6.12
 * [new tag]             1.6.13     -> 1.6.13
 * [new tag]             1.6.14     -> 1.6.14
 * [new tag]             1.6.15     -> 1.6.15
 * [new tag]             1.6.16     -> 1.6.16
 * [new tag]             1.6.17     -> 1.6.17
 * [new tag]             1.6.2      -> 1.6.2
 * [new tag]             1.6.3      -> 1.6.3
 * [new tag]             1.6.4      -> 1.6.4
 * [new tag]             1.6.5      -> 1.6.5
 * [new tag]             1.6.6      -> 1.6.6
 * [new tag]             1.6.7      -> 1.6.7
 * [new tag]             1.6.8      -> 1.6.8
 * [new tag]             1.6.9      -> 1.6.9
 * [new tag]             1.7.0      -> 1.7.0
 * [new tag]             1.7.1      -> 1.7.1
 * [new tag]             1.7.2      -> 1.7.2
 * [new tag]             1.7.3      -> 1.7.3
 * [new tag]             1.7.4      -> 1.7.4
 * [new tag]             1.7.5      -> 1.7.5
 * [new tag]             1.7.6      -> 1.7.6
 * [new tag]             1.7.7      -> 1.7.7
 * [new tag]             1.8.0      -> 1.8.0
 * [new tag]             1.8.1      -> 1.8.1
 * [new tag]             1.8.2      -> 1.8.2
 * [new tag]             1.8.3      -> 1.8.3
 * [new tag]             1.8.4      -> 1.8.4
 * [new tag]             1.8.5      -> 1.8.5
 * [new tag]             1.8.6      -> 1.8.6
 * [new tag]             1.9.0      -> 1.9.0
 * [new tag]             1.9.1      -> 1.9.1
 * [new tag]             1.9.2      -> 1.9.2
 * [new tag]             1.9.3      -> 1.9.3
 * [new tag]             2.0.0      -> 2.0.0
 * [new tag]             2.0.1      -> 2.0.1
 * [new tag]             2.0.2      -> 2.0.2
 * [new tag]             2.0.3      -> 2.0.3
 * [new tag]             2.0.4      -> 2.0.4
 * [new tag]             2.0.5      -> 2.0.5
 * [new tag]             2.0.6      -> 2.0.6
 * [new tag]             2.1.0      -> 2.1.0
 * [new tag]             2.1.1      -> 2.1.1
 * [new tag]             2.1.10     -> 2.1.10
 * [new tag]             2.1.11     -> 2.1.11
 * [new tag]             2.1.12     -> 2.1.12
 * [new tag]             2.1.13     -> 2.1.13
 * [new tag]             2.1.14     -> 2.1.14
 * [new tag]             2.1.15     -> 2.1.15
 * [new tag]             2.1.16     -> 2.1.16
 * [new tag]             2.1.2      -> 2.1.2
 * [new tag]             2.1.3      -> 2.1.3
 * [new tag]             2.1.4      -> 2.1.4
 * [new tag]             2.1.5      -> 2.1.5
 * [new tag]             2.1.6      -> 2.1.6
 * [new tag]             2.1.7      -> 2.1.7
 * [new tag]             2.1.8      -> 2.1.8
 * [new tag]             2.1.9      -> 2.1.9
 * [new tag]             2.2.0      -> 2.2.0
 * [new tag]             2.2.1      -> 2.2.1
 * [new tag]             2.2.10     -> 2.2.10
 * [new tag]             2.2.11     -> 2.2.11
 * [new tag]             2.2.12     -> 2.2.12
 * [new tag]             2.2.13     -> 2.2.13
 * [new tag]             2.2.14     -> 2.2.14
 * [new tag]             2.2.15     -> 2.2.15
 * [new tag]             2.2.16     -> 2.2.16
 * [new tag]             2.2.17     -> 2.2.17
 * [new tag]             2.2.2      -> 2.2.2
 * [new tag]             2.2.3      -> 2.2.3
 * [new tag]             2.2.4      -> 2.2.4
 * [new tag]             2.2.5      -> 2.2.5
 * [new tag]             2.2.6      -> 2.2.6
 * [new tag]             2.2.7      -> 2.2.7
 * [new tag]             2.2.8      -> 2.2.8
 * [new tag]             2.2.9      -> 2.2.9
 * [new tag]             2.3.0      -> 2.3.0
 * [new tag]             2.4.0      -> 2.4.0
 * [new tag]             2.4.1      -> 2.4.1
 * [new tag]             2.4.10     -> 2.4.10
 * [new tag]             2.4.11     -> 2.4.11
 * [new tag]             2.4.12     -> 2.4.12
 * [new tag]             2.4.13     -> 2.4.13
 * [new tag]             2.4.14     -> 2.4.14
 * [new tag]             2.4.15     -> 2.4.15
 * [new tag]             2.4.16     -> 2.4.16
 * [new tag]             2.4.2      -> 2.4.2
 * [new tag]             2.4.3      -> 2.4.3
 * [new tag]             2.4.4      -> 2.4.4
 * [new tag]             2.4.5      -> 2.4.5
 * [new tag]             2.4.6      -> 2.4.6
 * [new tag]             2.4.7      -> 2.4.7
 * [new tag]             2.4.8      -> 2.4.8
 * [new tag]             2.4.9      -> 2.4.9
 * [new tag]             2.5.0      -> 2.5.0
 * [new tag]             2.5.1      -> 2.5.1
 * [new tag]             2.5.10     -> 2.5.10
 * [new tag]             2.5.11     -> 2.5.11
 * [new tag]             2.5.12     -> 2.5.12
 * [new tag]             2.5.2      -> 2.5.2
 * [new tag]             2.5.3      -> 2.5.3
 * [new tag]             2.5.4      -> 2.5.4
 * [new tag]             2.5.5      -> 2.5.5
 * [new tag]             2.5.6      -> 2.5.6
 * [new tag]             2.5.7      -> 2.5.7
 * [new tag]             2.5.8      -> 2.5.8
 * [new tag]             2.5.9      -> 2.5.9
 * [new tag]             2.6.0      -> 2.6.0
 * [new tag]             2.6.1      -> 2.6.1
 * [new tag]             2.6.2      -> 2.6.2
 * [new tag]             2.7.0      -> 2.7.0
 * [new tag]             2.7.1      -> 2.7.1
 * [new tag]             2.7.2      -> 2.7.2
 * [new tag]             2.7.3      -> 2.7.3
 * [new tag]             2.7.4      -> 2.7.4
 * [new tag]             2.7.5      -> 2.7.5
 * [new tag]             2.7.6      -> 2.7.6
 * [new tag]             2.7.7      -> 2.7.7
 * [new tag]             3.0.0      -> 3.0.0
 * [new tag]             3.0.1      -> 3.0.1
 * [new tag]             3.0.10     -> 3.0.10
 * [new tag]             3.0.11     -> 3.0.11
 * [new tag]             3.0.2      -> 3.0.2
 * [new tag]             3.0.3      -> 3.0.3
 * [new tag]             3.0.4      -> 3.0.4
 * [new tag]             3.0.5      -> 3.0.5
 * [new tag]             3.0.6      -> 3.0.6
 * [new tag]             3.0.7      -> 3.0.7
 * [new tag]             3.0.8      -> 3.0.8
 * [new tag]             3.0.9      -> 3.0.9
 * [new tag]             3.1.0      -> 3.1.0
 * [new tag]             3.1.1      -> 3.1.1
 * [new tag]             3.1.10     -> 3.1.10
 * [new tag]             3.1.11     -> 3.1.11
 * [new tag]             3.1.12     -> 3.1.12
 * [new tag]             3.1.2      -> 3.1.2
 * [new tag]             3.1.3      -> 3.1.3
 * [new tag]             3.1.4      -> 3.1.4
 * [new tag]             3.1.5      -> 3.1.5
 * [new tag]             3.1.6      -> 3.1.6
 * [new tag]             3.1.7      -> 3.1.7
 * [new tag]             3.1.8      -> 3.1.8
 * [new tag]             3.1.9      -> 3.1.9
 * [new tag]             3.2.0      -> 3.2.0
 * [new tag]             3.2.1      -> 3.2.1
 * [new tag]             3.2.10     -> 3.2.10
 * [new tag]             3.2.11     -> 3.2.11
 * [new tag]             3.2.12     -> 3.2.12
 * [new tag]             3.2.13     -> 3.2.13
 * [new tag]             3.2.14     -> 3.2.14
 * [new tag]             3.2.15     -> 3.2.15
 * [new tag]             3.2.16     -> 3.2.16
 * [new tag]             3.2.17     -> 3.2.17
 * [new tag]             3.2.2      -> 3.2.2
 * [new tag]             3.2.3      -> 3.2.3
 * [new tag]             3.2.4      -> 3.2.4
 * [new tag]             3.2.5      -> 3.2.5
 * [new tag]             3.2.6      -> 3.2.6
 * [new tag]             3.2.7      -> 3.2.7
 * [new tag]             3.2.8      -> 3.2.8
 * [new tag]             3.2.9      -> 3.2.9
 * [new tag]             3.3.0      -> 3.3.0
 * [new tag]             3.3.1      -> 3.3.1
 * [new tag]             3.3.10     -> 3.3.10
 * [new tag]             3.3.11     -> 3.3.11
 * [new tag]             3.3.12     -> 3.3.12
 * [new tag]             3.3.13     -> 3.3.13
 * [new tag]             3.3.14     -> 3.3.14
 * [new tag]             3.3.15     -> 3.3.15
 * [new tag]             3.3.16     -> 3.3.16
 * [new tag]             3.3.2      -> 3.3.2
 * [new tag]             3.3.3      -> 3.3.3
 * [new tag]             3.3.4      -> 3.3.4
 * [new tag]             3.3.5      -> 3.3.5
 * [new tag]             3.3.6      -> 3.3.6
 * [new tag]             3.3.7      -> 3.3.7
 * [new tag]             3.3.8      -> 3.3.8
 * [new tag]             3.3.9      -> 3.3.9
 * [new tag]             3.4.0      -> 3.4.0
 * [new tag]             3.4.1      -> 3.4.1
 * [new tag]             3.4.10     -> 3.4.10
 * [new tag]             3.4.11     -> 3.4.11
 * [new tag]             3.4.2      -> 3.4.2
 * [new tag]             3.4.3      -> 3.4.3
 * [new tag]             3.4.4      -> 3.4.4
 * [new tag]             3.4.5      -> 3.4.5
 * [new tag]             3.4.6      -> 3.4.6
 * [new tag]             3.4.7      -> 3.4.7
 * [new tag]             3.4.8      -> 3.4.8
 * [new tag]             3.4.9      -> 3.4.9
 * [new tag]             3.5.0      -> 3.5.0
 * [new tag]             3.5.1      -> 3.5.1
 * [new tag]             3.5.10     -> 3.5.10
 * [new tag]             3.5.2      -> 3.5.2
 * [new tag]             3.5.3      -> 3.5.3
 * [new tag]             3.5.4      -> 3.5.4
 * [new tag]             3.5.5      -> 3.5.5
 * [new tag]             3.5.6      -> 3.5.6
 * [new tag]             3.5.7      -> 3.5.7
 * [new tag]             3.5.8      -> 3.5.8
 * [new tag]             3.5.9      -> 3.5.9
 * [new tag]             3.6.0      -> 3.6.0
 * [new tag]             3.6.1      -> 3.6.1
 * [new tag]             3.6.10     -> 3.6.10
 * [new tag]             3.6.11     -> 3.6.11
 * [new tag]             3.6.12     -> 3.6.12
 * [new tag]             3.6.13     -> 3.6.13
 * [new tag]             3.6.14     -> 3.6.14
 * [new tag]             3.6.15     -> 3.6.15
 * [new tag]             3.6.16     -> 3.6.16
 * [new tag]             3.6.17     -> 3.6.17
 * [new tag]             3.6.18     -> 3.6.18
 * [new tag]             3.6.19     -> 3.6.19
 * [new tag]             3.6.2      -> 3.6.2
 * [new tag]             3.6.20     -> 3.6.20
 * [new tag]             3.6.21     -> 3.6.21
 * [new tag]             3.6.3      -> 3.6.3
 * [new tag]             3.6.4      -> 3.6.4
 * [new tag]             3.6.5      -> 3.6.5
 * [new tag]             3.6.6      -> 3.6.6
 * [new tag]             3.6.7      -> 3.6.7
 * [new tag]             3.6.8      -> 3.6.8
 * [new tag]             3.6.9      -> 3.6.9
 * [new tag]             4.0.0      -> 4.0.0
 * [new tag]             4.0.1      -> 4.0.1
 * [new tag]             4.0.10     -> 4.0.10
 * [new tag]             4.0.11     -> 4.0.11
 * [new tag]             4.0.12     -> 4.0.12
 * [new tag]             4.0.13     -> 4.0.13
 * [new tag]             4.0.14     -> 4.0.14
 * [new tag]             4.0.15     -> 4.0.15
 * [new tag]             4.0.16     -> 4.0.16
 * [new tag]             4.0.2      -> 4.0.2
 * [new tag]             4.0.3      -> 4.0.3
 * [new tag]             4.0.4      -> 4.0.4
 * [new tag]             4.0.5      -> 4.0.5
 * [new tag]             4.0.6      -> 4.0.6
 * [new tag]             4.0.7      -> 4.0.7
 * [new tag]             4.0.8      -> 4.0.8
 * [new tag]             4.0.9      -> 4.0.9
HEAD is now at cdc54636e Merge pull request #15344 from samford/download-strategy-replace-in-place-sub
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

I have also tried running with the below command but get the exact same error.
(base) MacBook-Pro-3:~ jordan$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"